# Change value based on 'value label' for all variables

Tags: spss

I want to update some values of a variable based on the value label of that same variable:

In pseudo-code:

```
for V in var1 to var10:
  if value label of V is 'x':
    set value 99
```

Comment: I am looking for scripted solutions (that is, avoiding the user interface)

Comment: It's not so clear what you are asking - cells in SPSS do not contain value labels - they contain values. In the variable definition you can set value labels which will be attached to specific values in the output - each variable can have a few value labels or none, regardless of the number of the number of actual (or potential) values in the variable.

Comment: Right, thanks for clarifying the vocabulary @eli-k. Here is an attempt to rephrase:  Given the 'value label' of a variable I want to update its values (its cell) so if in the value labels we have something like `7 = 'x'`. Then given 'x' I want to replace all instances of 7 with, say, 99. But the issue is I don't know if it will be 7 or not -- thus I need to check the value label.

Answer (score 1):

First we'll create some fake data to demonstrate on:

```
data list list/a1 to a3 (3f1) notforuse (f1).
begin data 
1,2,2,55
2,1,4,66
3,4,1,77
end data.

value labels 
a1 1 'x1' 2 'x' 3 'x3'
/a2 1 'y1' 2 'a' 3 'b' 4 'x'
/a3 1 'n' 2 'x'
/notforuse 55 'nn' 66 "x".
```

Now to the actual task:

```
* first step is to create a list of  variable labels.
dataset name origdata.
DATASET DECLARE  vallabs.
OMS   /SELECT TABLES   /IF COMMANDS=['File Information'] SUBTYPES=['Variable Values']
  /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV  OUTFILE='vallabs' VIEWER=NO.
DISPLAY DICTIONARY.
OMSEND.
dataset activate vallabs.
* you now have a full list of your actual variable labels. next step is to select the variables you want to work on, and the labels you want to work on.

*to select the relevant variables.
select if any(var1 , "a1", "a2", "a3"). 
* can alternatively use the following: . 
select if char.index(var1, "a")>0.

*to set the new values for relevant labels:.
recode label ("x"=99)("y1"=999) into newval.
select if not missing(newval).

*now use the list to create a new syntax: .
cd 'yourpath\writeable directory'
write out='val lab syntax.sps' /"if ", var1, " = ", var2, " ", var1, " = ", newval, ".".
exe.

*now use the new syntax in the original data:.
dataset activate origdata.
insert file= 'val lab syntax.sps'.
exe.
```